# Redrawing of Win32 OpenGL context can't keep up with window resizing

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I've been working on an OpenGL-based application that runs directly on Win32. I've noticed an issue where when I resize the window, the drawing can't keep up around the edges. [Here's a video of the issue in action.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dErktQ1iJQs) (Note the bottom-right and top-right corners of the window)

I am running the redraw function inside of my `WM_SIZE` event, but it still has a slight delay.

If there is a way to make it not have this visual artifacting - great! If not, how can I keep the window from updating its size until the controls have been drawn?

Comment: [Use `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` instead of `WM_SIZE`.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080115-00/?p=23813) [The Remarks section of `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`'s MSDN page says it is more efficient to do so.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I would, but I have to handle "SIZE_MAXIMIZED" on the wparam, which is only sent on WM_SIZE.

This is because my window style covers the taskbar and I want to avoid that.

Comment: @zangent: There's nothing that prevents you from processing both WM_SIZE and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

Comment: Check what I linked again: WM_SIZE is artificially generated by `DefWindowProc()` if you let it handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`. Everything you can do with `WM_SIZE` can be done with `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, including `SIZE_MAXIMIZED`. Not sure what the exact conversion is.

Comment: I'm now using both - I'm using WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED for resize redrawing and WM_SIZE for checking on maximize. It's still slow though. The same artifacting occurs at the edges.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: What happens if you **only** use `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, which is what I was trying to get at?